# How to back up Cached data in Asp.Net MVC applications?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am building an application which builds a cache which is of big size. The cost of building the cache is again if it is lost is huge.

Is there any way to save the cached data in asp.Net MVC3 applications ?

Comment: Cached Data? Could mean anything. What are you caching?

Comment: I am caching a list of string (actually html strings that will be fetched from different application using WbeClient). The list can be as huge as of 10,000 +

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take another approach. could be, create database views for example

Keep in mind a few things, you can't have cached whole time because the app pool it's gonna recycle, so even you change the time interval, always gonna happen.

plus, changes in your app that can trigger the recycle

What trigger a immediate recycle?

anything changes in:

- Web.config
- Machine.config
- Global.asax
- Bin directory
- App_Code
- Views strong typed

What trigger a delayed recycle?

Occur with changes in .aspx, .cs/.vb files.

Comment: Agreed Zach. What should i follow then ?

Comment: reading your other comment, +/- 10k strings from different aplications, you can built database table, drop and create each time the app starts. I think will be more healthy